# Descompactar string GZipB64 - Java

Tags: java, base64

Estou fazendo um projeto api rest onde tenho retorno de json e um dos campos vem como base64, preciso descompactar o campo para poder ter a string xml ou json.

Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizado para obter o retorno.

```
public final void run() {
    try {
        OkHttpClient httpsClient = createHttpsClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(call).build();

        Response response = httpsClient.newCall(request).execute();

        if (!response.isSuccessful())
            throw new NfseException(NFSeMessageErrorEnum.INVALID_ENV, Integer.toString(response.code()));

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SefinNacionalXml sefinNfse = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), SefinNacionalXml.class);
        
        byte[]  base64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sefinNfse.getNfseXmlGZipB64());
        String msgDecode  = new String(base64, "UTF-8");
        System.out.print(msgDecode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

E na hora de tentar descompartar e ter a string, está vindo um monte de caracteres especiais.

Retorno

�

Conteúdo do campo que estou tentando converter para string.

```
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
```